# How to find the data replication in Apache CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

There are two couchDB instances running in two different machines namely Master A & B. There is a database called sampledb in both the machines where data replication is set. Is there is any way to find out where the data replication is set, whether in Master A or in Master B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching all the options in Apache CouchDB, I found that the replication of the database can be found from the "Status" option in CouchDB.